# google sheet split() truncating value because it thinks it's a number?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have the following working script:
`ss.getRange('E'+lastRow).setFormula('INDEX(SPLIT(B'+lastRow+',".Upload.",0),1,1)');`

This works on the below table (columns B:E):

[image]

The only problem is Google Sheets insists on rounding the value in E. Which is strange since, both column B and E are in plain text format. How do I get the full value '44138.5687497917' to show using the script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
'INDEX(SPLIT(B'+lastRow+',".Upload.",0),1,1)'
```

by

```
'INDEX(SPLIT(B'+lastRow+',".Upload.",0),1,1)&""'
```

(append an blank TEXT value)

Another option

```
'TO_TEXT(INDEX(SPLIT(B'+lastRow+',".Upload.",0),1,1))'
```

Resources

- https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094285?hl=en

Comment: The first option works. To_Text() yields the same truncated result.

Comment: @testing123 Thanks for let me know. I think that it's a bug ("TO_TEXT is equivalent to prefixing a number with an apostrophe (')")